# Printing APA cite in place with out citation

Tags: citing, apacite

I am trying to list only my publication within `my_pub.bib` file. Is there any way I could do this using `apacite` package.

According to https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Bibliography_management_with_biblatex `biblatex` can use something like

```
\printbibliography[type=article,title={Articles only}]
```

to list it in place.

This is what I have so far

```
\documentclass[]{article}
\usepackage{apacite}

\begin{document}

\nocite{*}

\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{other_pub, my_pub}

\end{document}
```

`\nocite{*}` lists all non-cited papers from both bib files.

I wanted to list all papers in `my_pub.bib` to be listed under a given section. How would I do that?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! BTW, `\begin{document}` is missing.

Comment: Any news or solved?

Comment: @Bobyandbob Nope, I am writing them manually.